# Reusing the Result of a Controller in another Controller in the Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

Apologies if this has been answered already - I've had a look and can't find anything.

Using the Play framework, I have defined two controllers - one is a public API that returns JSON, and one is a consumer of this API which presents the JSON as HTML. E.g. my routes file look as follows:

```
GET     /foos       controllers.App.foos() #produces HTML
GET     /api/foos   controllers.API.foos() #produces JSON
```

A requirement of the project is that our data should only be accessed via our public API. Therefore, the way that I'd like to implement this is to have `App.foos()` invoke `API.foos()`, parse the JSON result, and pass it to a template to be rendered. For example:

```
public App extends Controller {
  public static Result foos() {
    Result result = API.foos();
    // TODO: get the JSON out of the result object
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can extract the JSON from the result object? I can get the body of the object as an Enumerator using `((SimpleResult)result.getWrappedResult()).body()`, but I am still unclear how I can get out the JSON.

Because I am new to the Play framework, perhaps I am going about this wrong and there is an easier/better way to do this?

Many thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to expose the underlying method.

```
public Api extends Controller {

  public static Result foos() {
    Ok(foosJson());
  }

  public static JsValue foosJson() {
    // ...
  }
}

public App extends Controller {

  public static Result foos() {
    JsValue json = API.foosJson();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, we are required to use the API directly, and so I think this may not be allowed. We've decided to go down the [web services](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaWS) route for the time being - this may actually be preferable as the public api might be physically separated from the consumer in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Using the web service is indeed in your case best. Dealing with the contents of results is very tricky because the body is not part of the  interface. You would have to match against the various sub classes (or implementations) and future changes could easily break that. I think you made the right call to go over HTTP.